# Openrowset with bulk option cannot retrieve records due to an invalid type DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

When trying to read a parquet file with the `openrowset` and `bulk` options I encounter the following error:

`Error handling external file: 'Inserting value to batch for column type DATE failed. Invalid argument provided.'`

This problem indicates that the file couldn't be read because the data contains values that are not DATE type - indeed, there are `undefined` and `0001-01-01` records, so when the `BULK` operation is performed these values prevent from loading the entire parquet file (see the code from below).

```
SELECT
TOP 100 
POST_SEARCH_DATE,
SEARCH_DATE 

FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2022-01-01/**',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    
) AS [result]
```

One alternative I thought was to convert the column to a varchar to bypass the error but unfortunately, that didn't make any difference (see below).

```
SELECT
TOP 100 
POST_SEARCH_DATE,
SEARCH_DATE

FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2022-01-01/**',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    
) AS [result]

WHERE cast(POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE as varchar(100))!= 'undefined'

and cast (SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE as varchar(100)) != 'undefined'
and cast (SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE as varchar(100)) != '0001-01-01'
and cast(POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE as varchar(100))!= '0001-01-01'
```

I found some suggestions about inserting every record into a temporary table and from there you can disregard the records that fail. Can someone help me to give me more details about this solution or another alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using `WITH` to define the data types, while using OPENROWSET?

```
SELECT
  TOP 100 
  POST_SEARCH_DATE,
  SEARCH_DATE,
  EXAMPLE_COL


FROM
OPENROWSET(
    BULK 'https://test/refined-parquet/data/v1.0/loaddt=2022-01-01/**',
    FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    WITH (
        [SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 3,
        [POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 2,
        [EXAMPLE_COL] VARCHAR(100)
) AS [r]
```

Comment: It works for one column! How can I retrieve both now? I tried to do the same for the `POST_SEARCH_DATE` and I encountered the following: `Duplicate column ordinal cannot be provided in WITH schema clause.`

Comment: @abautista updated the code sample, basically removed the ordinal number in the end, and added another definition separated by comma.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nisd! Now I am able to see the two columns with its correct values. One last thing is that if I want to see another column then I need to define it in the data types, i.e., `EXAMPLE` contains `string` values, but when I try to see its contents then I found the same values from `[POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE]`. This is how I defined my columns: `[SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2,
    [POST_SEARCH_DEPARTURE_DATE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2 [EXAMPLE] VARCHAR(100) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2`. I even deleted the collate but didn't work :(

Comment: @abautista your missing an comma, just before the definition of [EXAMPLE]

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to insert the comma and I was hoping this could have been the solution but it wasn't

Comment: Thank you @Nisd! I figured out the problem and your solution works as expected. I just did some minor changes to your solution and I hope you can accept them, so the community is aware about them.